# Are there MVC embedded system GUI examples?

Tags: model-view-controller, user-interface, embedded

I'd like to apply the MVC pattern to a GUI we are developing for an embedded system. In this case my understanding is we would need to provide the underlying framework for listener/event actions between the Controller and View. Also, I have seen some examples where the Model send an event to the View, but perhaps that is not correct. Does that seem correct?

Does anyone know of a framework targeted to embedded devices that may have this capability?

Answer (score 1):

If your embedded device supports Java, eRCP would be the best GUI framework in that case.
Check out: http://www.eclipse.org/ercp/

Model sends event to view is a way to notify the view updated about things has been changed in model. It's normal communication between M & V in MVC. However, the "view" here should be a *generic view* which is bound via an "observable" interface, not a concrete one.

For example:

- Abstract View: Clock (generic interface)
- Concrete View: Digital Clock, Analog Clock <--implementation of Clock
- Model: Time <-- "knows" Clock but not Digital or Analog...

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest the Qt Toolkit. But you don't give any mention of your platform capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a linux platform. Try Enlightenment the best GUI I have ever seen.....